# How to force Liquibase not to put the schema name into the index name?

Tags: xml, postgresql, indexing, syntax-error, liquibase

I have a project where I use PostgreSQL 9.5 as RDBMS and Liquibase 3.5.3 to generate the database entities. I wanted to create an index on a table with the following XML:

```
    <createIndex indexName="idx_entity_audit_event_entity_id"
        tableName="jhi_entity_audit_event">
        <column name="entity_id" type="bigint"/>
    </createIndex>
```

The generated SQL command is the following:

```
    CREATE INDEX public.idx_entity_audit_event_entity_id ON
                                            public.jhi_entity_audit_event(entity_id)
```

When executing the Liquibase changeset, I got the following error:

```
      Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
      Position: 20 [Failed SQL: CREATE INDEX public.idx_entity_audit_event_entity_id ON public.jhi_entity_audit_event(entity_id)]
```

I've tried to execute the above script manually as well in pgAdmin 4, and got the same error. I have tried to manually recreate the index again, but I have skipped the schema name `public` from the index name and it worked.
I am not sure if it is a Liquibase or Postgres issue, or simply the Liquibase and Postgres versions aren't in sync, but I can't make it working. If anyone has an idea, please share it with me and the community.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the PostgreSQL documentation for CREATE INDEX, you will find the following statement:

> *name*
>
> The name of the index to be created. No schema name can be included
>   here; the index is always created in the same schema as its parent
>   table. If the name is omitted, PostgreSQL chooses a suitable name
>   based on the parent table's name and the indexed column name(s).

Therefore no schema name can be included in the name of the index.